# MAX() and MAX() OVER PARTITION BY produces error 3504 in Teradata Query

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, teradata, database-partitioning

I am trying to produce a results table with the last completed course date for each course code, as well as the last completed course code overall for each employee. Below is my query:

```
SELECT employee_number,
       MAX(course_completion_date) 
           OVER (PARTITION BY course_code) AS max_course_date,
       MAX(course_completion_date) AS max_date
FROM employee_course_completion
WHERE course_code IN ('M910303', 'M91301R', 'M91301P')
GROUP BY employee_number
```

This query produces the following error:

```
3504 : Selected non-aggregate values must be part of the associated group
```

If I remove the MAX() OVER (PARTITION BY...) line, the query executes just fine, so I've isolated the problem to that line, but after searching these forums and the internet I can't see what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone help?

Comment: Because you're using OVER with reference to the MAX, SQL sees these as analytic functions - not aggregates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Ponies says in a comment, you cannot mix OLAP functions with aggregate functions.

Perhaps it's easier to get the last completion date for each employee, and join that to a dataset containing the last completion date for each of the three targeted courses.

This is an untested idea that should hopefully put you down the right path:

```
  SELECT employee_number,
         course_code,
         MAX(course_completion_date) AS max_date,
         lcc.LAST_COURSE_COMPLETED
    FROM employee_course_completion ecc
         LEFT JOIN (
             SELECT employee_number,
                    MAX(course_completion_date) AS LAST_COURSE_COMPLETED
               FROM employee_course_completion
              WHERE course_code IN ('M910303', 'M91301R', 'M91301P')
         ) lcc
         ON lcc.employee_number = ecc.employee_number
   WHERE course_code IN ('M910303', 'M91301R', 'M91301P')
GROUP BY employee_number, course_code, lcc.LAST_COURSE_COMPLETED
```

Answer (score 10):

Logically OLAP functions are calculated after GROUP BY/HAVING, so you can only access columns in GROUP BY or columns with an aggregate function. Following looks strange, but is Standard SQL:

```
SELECT employee_number,
       MAX(MAX(course_completion_date)) 
           OVER (PARTITION BY course_code) AS max_course_date,
       MAX(course_completion_date) AS max_date
FROM employee_course_completion
WHERE course_code IN ('M910303', 'M91301R', 'M91301P')
GROUP BY employee_number, course_code
```

And as Teradata allows re-using an alias this also works:

```
SELECT employee_number,
       MAX(max_date) 
           OVER (PARTITION BY course_code) AS max_course_date,
       MAX(course_completion_date) AS max_date
FROM employee_course_completion
WHERE course_code IN ('M910303', 'M91301R', 'M91301P')
GROUP BY employee_number, course_code
```

Comment: You have stated that **olap** functions are calculated after **group by/having**, but in you above code you are using the `course_code` in the partition clause, which is not part of the **group by** clause. The above code does not work in oracle. The error is 'ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression`

Comment: @frank: Correct, `course_code` must be added to `GROUP BY`

Comment: thanks for the confirmation. New to analytic functions was'nt sure if I was right.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old question, but I've been asked by someone else something similar.

I don't have TeraData, but can't you do the following?

```
SELECT employee_number,
       course_code,
       MAX(course_completion_date)                                     AS max_course_date,
       MAX(course_completion_date) OVER (PARTITION BY employee_number) AS max_date
FROM employee_course_completion
WHERE course_code IN ('M910303', 'M91301R', 'M91301P')
GROUP BY employee_number, course_code
```

The `GROUP BY` now ensures one row per course per employee.  This means that you just need a straight `MAX()` to get the `max_course_date`.

Before your `GROUP BY` was just giving one row per employee, and the `MAX() OVER()` was trying to give multiple results for that one row *(one per course)*.

Instead, you now need the `OVER()` clause to get the `MAX()` for the employee as a whole.  This is now legitimate because each individual row gets just one answer (as it is derived from a super-set, not a sub-set).  Also, for the same reason, the `OVER()` clause now refers to a valid scalar value, as defined by the `GROUP BY` clause; `employee_number`.

Perhaps a short way of saying this would be that an `aggregate` with an `OVER()` clause must be a super-set of the `GROUP BY`, not a sub-set.

Create your query with a `GROUP BY` at the level that represents the rows you want, then specify `OVER()` clauses if you want to aggregate at a higher level.

Comment: This will also produce the same error message. Logically OLAP functions are calculated **after** GROUP bY/HAVING, so you can only access columns in GROUP BY or columns with an aggregate function. Following looks strange, but is Standard SQL: **MAX(MAX(course_completion_date)) OVER (PARTITION BY employee_number)** And as Teradata allows re-using an alias this also works: **MAX(max_course_date) OVER (PARTITION BY employee_number)**

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work even though this was forever ago.

```
SELECT employee_number, Row_Number()  
   OVER (PARTITION BY course_code ORDER BY course_completion_date DESC ) as rownum
FROM employee_course_completion
WHERE course_code IN ('M910303', 'M91301R', 'M91301P')
   AND rownum = 1
```

If you want to get the last Id if the date is the same then you can use this assuming your primary key is Id.

```
SELECT employee_number, Row_Number()  
   OVER (PARTITION BY course_code ORDER BY course_completion_date DESC, Id Desc) as rownum    FROM employee_course_completion
WHERE course_code IN ('M910303', 'M91301R', 'M91301P')
   AND rownum = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT employee_number, course_code, MAX(course_completion_date) AS max_date
FROM employee_course_completion
WHERE course_code IN ('M910303', 'M91301R', 'M91301P')
GROUP BY employee_number, course_code
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Thanks for posting an answer but it needs an explanation on why it solves the problem.